When I ask for motivations, what I really mean is an assumptions check
Why don't Hikaru, Fabi & Nepo buy out Liren so the 3 of them have a playoff to face Gukesh?
Like I already said:

It's most likely. 1 of my assumptions is wrong. I mean to ask which of the assumptions are wrong. However, if none of the assumptions are wrong, then I think this could be an answer like

None of the assumptions are wrong. Beyond this is speculation.


So what I'm really asking is eg

legality of the matter.
if Hikaru would be the runner-up instead of that there's a playoff

What's opinion-based about this? I find it very factual:

Is it legal?
What happens if ever?


Don't disguise your question about the rules as a question about motivations. If your question is as straightforward as you say it is, make that clear to us.
If you mean to ask if it is legal, just ask that.
That takes about two sentences, not seven hundred words and a dozen numbered assumptions.
The more you write, the more likely people are going to misunderstand you.
